# How to make text selection visible in child, while mouse over draggable parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a box, that is draggable, inside this box I have another box, that contains text. I want to be able to be able to select the text but also to drag/drop parent. The problem I have is, how can I show selection, when leaving box with text? Right now selection highlight is disappearing when I mouse is out, and appear again, when mouse is over again. Here's the code. Select a text and leave green square.

```js
const innerBox = document.getElementById('inner');
const outerBox = document.getElementById('outer');

innerBox.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
 outerBox.setAttribute('draggable', false);
});

innerBox.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
 outerBox.setAttribute('draggable', true);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#outer {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: red;
}

#inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer" draggable="true">
  <div id="inner">Select me!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding user-select:auto to the inner box!

```js
const innerBox = document.getElementById('inner');
const outerBox = document.getElementById('outer');

innerBox.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
 outerBox.setAttribute('draggable', false);
});

innerBox.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
 outerBox.setAttribute('draggable', true);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#outer {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: red;
}

#inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  user-select:auto
}
```

```html
<div id="outer" draggable="true">
  <div id="inner">Select me!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer, because it's working on my test code. Unfortunately I'm unable to make it work on real code :( I need to use it in React and whatever I do, selection disappears when cursor leave the area and appears again, when cursor came back. I'll have to dig into it.